# Timeout Error Sql Exception 0 x 80131904 .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlexception, dbcommand

I'm using .NET Core and trying to figure out why the SQL Server localdb is not working. I am using Dapper to connect to the database and I used breakpoints to check if all the data was there and it was. I get this error when trying to call the `ExecuteReader` method from the `DbCommand` class.

My SQL Server connection string is:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=PostStackDatabaseV2;Integrated Security=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

I use the localdb SQL Server database and tried connecting to it using SQL Server Management Studio and it was successful. The code where I register the user is here:

```
public int RegisterUser(string connectionStr, string name, string email, string password)
{
    using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        // hash password here before it goes into the database
        var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher();
        string hashedPassword = passwordHasher.HashPassword(password);

        var isAdmin = 0;
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

        conn.Open();

        using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (DbCommand registerCommand = (DbCommand)conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    registerCommand.Transaction = (DbTransaction)transaction;
                    registerCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES (@UserName, @UserEmail, @UserPassword, @CreatedAt, @Admin)";
                    registerCommand.Connection = (DbConnection)conn;

                    var firstNameParam = registerCommand.CreateParameter();
                    firstNameParam.ParameterName = "@UserName";
                    firstNameParam.Value = name;
                    registerCommand.Parameters.Add(firstNameParam);

                    var emailParam = registerCommand.CreateParameter();
                    emailParam.ParameterName = "@UserEmail";
                    emailParam.Value = email;
                    registerCommand.Parameters.Add(emailParam);

                    var passwordParam = registerCommand.CreateParameter();
                    passwordParam.ParameterName = "@UserPassword";
                    passwordParam.Value = password;
                    registerCommand.Parameters.Add(passwordParam);

                    var createdAtParam = registerCommand.CreateParameter();
                    createdAtParam.ParameterName = "@CreatedAt";
                    createdAtParam.Value = currentTime;
                    registerCommand.Parameters.Add(createdAtParam);

                    var adminParam = registerCommand.CreateParameter();
                    adminParam.ParameterName = "@Admin";
                    adminParam.Value = isAdmin;
                    registerCommand.Parameters.Add(adminParam);

                    int rowsAffected = registerCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    // conn.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(rowsAffected);

                    int userId = RetrieveUserId(email, connectionStr);

                    return userId;
                }
                catch
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    conn.Close();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private int RetrieveUserId(string userEmail, string connectionStr)
{
    using (DbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (var retrieveCmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                retrieveCmd.Connection = conn;
                retrieveCmd.Transaction = transaction;
                retrieveCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Email = @UserEmail";
                retrieveCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                retrieveCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserEmail", userEmail));

                try
                {
                    var reader = retrieveCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string userIdStr = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        int userId = int.Parse(userIdStr);

                        if (userId != -1)
                        {
                            // conn.Close();
                            return userId;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // conn.Close();
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                catch(DbException err)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DbException.GetType: {0}", err.GetType());
                    Console.WriteLine("DbException.Source: {0}", err.Source);
                    Console.WriteLine("DbException.ErrorCode: {0}", err.ErrorCode);
                    Console.WriteLine("DbException.Message: {0}", err.Message);
                    return -1;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`RegisterUser` is called first which inserts the user's data into the database and the rows affected comes back as 1 instead of 0.  When I right-click on the database Users table and clicked "view data" I don't see any data.

The `RetrieveUserId` method is called to retrieve the user Id generated automatically by SQL Server after the data is inserted. The `retrieveCmd.ExecuteReader()` line is where the timeout happens. I have tried the `dbo.` prefix in front of `Users` in the SQL statement and it didn't work either.

I also tried the async versions of the `ExecuteReader` and `ExecuteNonQuery` methods and that didn't work. I am lost as what to do next any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing the code in `RetrieveUserId` I'm only guessing, however: (1) you're opening a transaction in `RegisterUser` to insert a row in `Users`, which will put an update lock on the row/index(es)/table; (2) `RetrieveUserId` is probably opening a second connection to select from `Users` and will be blocking on the lock taken on the first connection. In `RegisterUser` why don't you add a `@UserID` output parameter and add `; select @UserID=scope_identity();` to your `CommandText`?

Comment: Thanks a lot that actually fixed it thank you very much I spent all day on this I appreciate it.